# Change the dimension of the result of PointLegend?

Tags: plotting, legending, visualization

Here is the output of `PointLegend`:

```
a = {"a", "ai", "an", "ang", "ao", "b", "c", "ch", "d", "e", "ei", "en", "eng", "er", "f", "g", "h", "i", "ia", "ian", "iang", "iao", "ie", "ii", "iii", "in", "ing", "iong", "iou", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "ong", "ou", "p", "q", "r", "s", "sh", "sil", "sp", "t", "u", "ua", "uai", "uan", "uang", "uei", "uen", "ueng", "uo", "v", "van", "ve", "vn", "x", "z", "zh"}; 

PointLegend["Rainbow", a, LegendMarkerSize -> 15, LegendLayout -> "Column"]
```

[image]

It's like a 9*7 matrix, how to reshape it? like 5*13.

I find the `Head` of the result is still `PointLegend`.So Can't using `List` method to reshape it.

However I found If changing `LegendLayout` to `LegendLayout -> "Automatic"`.
It seems it construct from the `List`

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PointLegend["Rainbow", a, LegendMarkerSize -> 15, 
 LegendLayout -> {"Row", 5}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
PointLegend["Rainbow", a, LegendMarkerSize -> 15, 
 LegendLayout -> (Grid[Row /@ # & /@ Partition[#, 13, 13, 1, {}], 
     Alignment -> Left] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, It's a undocumented trick！Thanks！